# Is this possible with Magento Community

Tags: paypal, downloadable, pdf

I would like to set up an ecommerce shop which I can host myself and customize myself if possible. I would like to know if Magento Community is capable for the following features:

- Payment via Credit Card (Visa / Mastercard / American Express), Paypal and normal Bank Account
- Sell software and making this software downloadable via Magento
- sell ebooks (pdf and other formats)

Looking forward to your reponses!

Comment: Yes, Yes and Yes.

Comment: I guess you should, rather review Magento demo first, before posting this question.

Comment: The simple answer is yes to all, as already provided. The more complex answer is that if you want to provide 10s to 100s thousands of products, Magento can handle it, but you need specialist architecture to make the store usable. So it all depends on how large you are trying to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can host Magento CE (and EE) yourself, but for any serious shop you'll need a good hosting provider. You could host the server yourself if you want to, with a fast (upload) and stable connection.

For payment you can use CC, Paypal and bank accounts. We use that, but we use a payment provider for those. That makes it secure and a lot easier to setup. With a payment provider you only need to setup their software in Magento, and then everything (they offer) works. This will cost some money, but it's worth it and it's a lot less work.

You can use Magento to sell downloads, whether they are ebooks or software.